# Reference to Observed class as member variable of the Observer in C++

Tags: c++, reference, observer-pattern

I'm implementing an Observer pattern in C++.
The observer objects need to access to member variables of the Observed class when they are notified. By now I've solved this thing adding a reference to the Observed class as a member variable of the Observer as follows:

```cpp
class Observer{
     public:   
     Observer(const Observable& obs) : observed_(obs){}
     void notify(const Event& event){
         // get Observable member and do stuff
     }
     private:
     const Observable& observed_;
}
class Observable{

      public:
      void notify(const Event& event){
           //observer list.notify
      }

}
```

Is the reference a good way for this pattern or is better to use other strategies?

Comment: Personally I prefer pointer rather than references as *members* of a class. That way, it's possible to assign Observers, which may be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend in this case having the Observable instance sent as a member of Event, this way an Observer can watch more than one object, and you also achieve loose coupling between the two classes.

Comment: In a complex architecture this might be a problem since I'd implement the observer class with generic events (usually Observer is a base class inherited by different Concrete Observer), thus, having a specific class as a parameter of the notify function would require using dynamic_cast which, except from some particular cases, is usually a sign of bad design. Anyway, I did not specify in the question that the observer is inherited so your suggestion can be helpful in some cases.

Comment: You can use generics in order to avoid casts, assuming the Observer watches objects of the same type.